# TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, function

So I am new to python and I am currently learning about functions. So I have created a following function which I don't know why is not working.

```
   def open_netflix():
    print('Opening Netflix')
    x = str(input('Enter the Season you want to play:  '))
    y = int(input('Which season of',x,'you want to play?'))
    z = int(input('Which episode?'))
    print('Playing',x,y,z)
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
Opening Netflix
Enter the Season you want to play:  Breaking Bad
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-82ce4ad2e7d2> in <module>
----> 1 open_netflix()

<ipython-input-17-917a60c59ffa> in open_netflix()
      2     print('Opening Netflix')
      3     x = str(input('Enter the Season you want to play:  '))
----> 4     y = int(input('Which season of',x,'you want to play?'))
      5     z = int(input('Which episode?'))
      6     print('Playing',x,y,z)

TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I don't know what the problem is. Looking forward for help.

Comment: Why is the error mentioning `raw_input` (a Python-2–only function) rather than `input`, the one actually in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` only takes one argument. You're passing in three on the line:

`y = int(input('Which season of',x,'you want to play?'))`

Please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

You probably want to try out f-strings.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: Yes I read it. I was not familiar with the term f-string. Now I am. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`input` is not like `print`; it doesn't concatenate its arguments into a single string. You need to do that yourself, for example using an f-string.

```
x = int(input(f'Which season of {x} do you want to play?')
```